# Delete the generated script in QC

Tags: testing, hp-quality-center

By mistake I have generated the script for one of test case in quality center.
Now I am unable to execute it manually.
Please guide me how to remove the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as:
Go to Test Plan
Select test case and change view to Grid view
Change Test Type to Manual

Comment: Pradeep's solution works fine only if you are sure the converted test will never have to generate script in future. Just in case if you try to re-generate script you will see issues.

Answer (score 1):

In Test Lab, if you click little black arrow next to Run button, you will see the option "Run Manually" for any automated test. So you don't have to change it back to manual to run it manually.

If you want to fix it though, Pradeep's solution is the way to go. Right-click -> Delete removes entire test, not only script.

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
If you have privilege to delete scripts from QC you should be able to just right click it and delete it, alternatively there should be an option in menu.
If you can't do this check with your QC admin who has proper privileges in given project.

BTW this is not really programming question, expect it to be closed soon.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I am unable to find any such option in QC.